# For Lebesgue integral theory, whether an integrable sequence of functions converging a.e. converges in L1 under a given "integral finite condition"

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

$\quad$ Let $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ is a measurable set, on which there is an integrable function sequence $\{f_n\}$,i.e. $f_n\in\mathcal L^1(E),n\ge1$, which satisfies $f_n\to f,\mathrm{a.e.}$ and satisfies the following "integral finite condition":
\begin{equation}
\sup_n\int_E|f_n|\ln(2+|f_n|)<\infty.
\end{equation}
$\quad$ Question: Does $f_n$ converge in $\mathcal L^1$? a.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n-f|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\|
f_n-f\right\|_{\mathcal L^1}=0.
\end{equation}

---

Edit: Thanks to *@Cauchy's Sequence* for the counterexample $\frac1n\chi_{[0,n]}$. What happens to this problem if we add the condition that the measure of $E$ is finite: $m(E)<\infty$? Can we give another counterexample that satisfies this condition? Or now can this proposition proved to be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E = \mathbb{R}$ and $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \chi_{[0, n]}$ for $n \ge 1$. Clearly $|f_n| \le 1$ for all $n$ and $f_n \to 0$ a.e. So all of your hypotheses are satisfied but $f_n$ does not converge in $L^1$ since $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n| = 1 $$ for all $n$.

The story is different if $E$ has finite measure. The answer is positive in this case. To see this, you need the following special case of the [Vitali convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem#Finite_measure_case): Suppose $(f_n)$ is a uniformly integrable sequence in $L^1(E, \mu)$, i.e.

$$ \lim_{M \to \infty} \sup_n \int_{|f_n| \ge M} |f_n| \, d\mu = 0. $$

If $(f_n)$ converges in measure to $f$, then it also converges in $L^1(E, \mu)$ to $f$.

Now, set $\Phi(x) = x \ln(2 + x)$. Clearly, $\frac{\Phi(x)}{x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Using this property and the hypothesis

$$ C := \sup_n \int_E \Phi(|f_n|) \, d\mu < \infty, $$

we show that $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable. Choose $N$ large enough so that $\frac{C}{N} < \varepsilon$. There exists $M_0$ such that $\Phi(x) > Nx$ for all $|x| \ge M_0$. If $M \ge M_0$, then

$$ \int_{|f_n| \ge M} |f_n| \, d\mu \le \int_{|f_n| \ge M} \frac{\Phi(|f_n|)}{N} \, d\mu \le \frac{C}{N} < \varepsilon$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable.

The claim then follows from Vitali's convergence theorem.

Comment: It's wonderful. Thanks a lot. I've tried a few examples before, including $n\chi_{[0,\frac1n]}$, which is similar to your example, but doesn't satisfy that condition. I couldn't figure it out, and I had no clue how to prove it. Now it seems to be false (but I don't know what does this problem want to show? Maybe there's a typo or something? For example, let $E$ be of finite measure.)

Comment: @daidaitx  I edited my answer to cover the finite measure case.

Comment: @Sequence I have read your supplement, thank you very much. But this was my first encounter with the concept of uniformly integrable, and I still had trouble figuring out how to get this sequence of functions to be uniformly integrable.

Comment: @daidaitx I added the proof to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I see. Thanks again!